# How to select certain value from complicated dictionary

Tags: python

So I am trying to get the state code from certain positions on a map using shapely.
I have found a way to check in which state a position/coordinate is, however I want to print just the abbreviated state code, not the whole dictionary/feature.

My code looks like this:

```
point = Point(-90, 38.62)

for state in data['features']:
    polygon = shape(state['geometry'])
    if polygon.contains(point):
        print ('Found containing polygon:', state)
```

Which prints this:

```
Found containing polygon: {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'STATE_NAME': 'Illinois', 'DRAWSEQ': 27, 'STATE_FIPS': '17', 'SUB_REGION': 'East North Central', 'STATE_ABBR': 'IL'}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-88.07159127841085, 37.51103836239962], [-88.08791027842605, 37.47632136236729], [-88.3117422786345, 37.44290336233617], [-88.35921427867872, 37.40936136230492], [-88.41989327873523, 37.42034336231515], [-88.46768627877974, 37.40080836229696], [-88.51136527882042, 37.29690536220019], [-88.5014692788112, 37.25783636216381], ....................
```

How do I get just 'IL' in my output?

I have tried:

```
print ('Found containing polygon:', state.get('STATE_ABBR'))
```

But this gave me 'None' instead of 'IL'

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

> But this gave me 'None' instead of 'IL'

Of course, your `state` dict doesn't have a `STATE_ABBR` key, its three keys are `type`, `properties` and `geometry`. Had you used regular indexing you'd have gotten a clearer `KeyError`.

`STATE_ABBR` is part of the `properties` sub-dict, so you first need to access *that*:

```py
state['properties']['STATE_ABBR']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the correct key in the dictionary:

```
print('Found containing polygon:', state['properties']['STATE_ABBR'])
```